# NoReverseMatch on extra enpoint in GenericViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
urls.py

app_name = "auth"

urlpatterns = [
    path("token/", TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair"),
    path("token/refresh/", TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="token_refresh"),
    path(
        "password/confirm/<str:uid>/<str:token>/",
        PasswordResetViewSet.as_view({"post": "password_reset_confirm"}, name="password_reset_confirm"),
    ),
    path(
        "password/reset/",
        PasswordResetViewSet.as_view({"post": "send_reset_password_link"}),
        name="password_send_link",
    ),
]

views.py

class PasswordResetViewSet(GenericViewSet):

    def get_permissions(self):
        return [permissions.AllowAny()]
    def get_serializer_class(self) -> type[Serializer]:
        action_serializer_map = {
            "send_reset_password_link": ResetPasswordSerializer,
            "confirm_password_changed": ResetPasswordConfirmSerializer,
        }
        return action_serializer_map[self.action]

    @extend_schema(request=ResetPasswordSerializer, responses={201: {}, 404: {}})
    @action(methods=["POST"], detail=False)
    def send_reset_password_link(self, request):
        serializer = ResetPasswordSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(
            data=reset_password_link_service(
                email=serializer.validated_data.get("email")
            )
        )

    @extend_schema(
        request=ResetPasswordConfirmSerializer,
    )
    @action(methods=["POST"], detail=False)
    def password_reset_confirm(self, request):
        return Response()
```

Trying to do reverse("auth:password_reset_confirm", kwargs={uid: uid, token: token}) gives me NoReverseMatch. Really do not know what is going wrong here... Suggestions? Adding usual FBV to the same namespace "auth" works great.

Comment: Changing viewname to "password_reset_confirm_view" didnt help. I thought previous one was shadowing built-in django view